# No Output of the apparent right "D3.js - Code" (Simple Scatterplot)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new in D3.js and can't fix a seemingly small problem. The thing is I don't realy understand what's wrong with "my" code. The error that I get on the console tells me: "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' ", which doesn't make any sense for me. May be some of you can help me with this. Here it is:

```
     var xyr = [
{x:1,y:1,r:1},
{x:2,y:2,r:2},
{x:3,y:3,r:3}
          ];

var body = d3.select("body");
var svg = body.append("svg").attr("width",250).attr("height",250);

var scaleX = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,250]);
var scaleY = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,250]);

function render(data){
//Data Binding
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);

scaleX.domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){ return d.x; }));
scaleY.domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){ return d.y; }));

  //Debugging (working correct  --> 125)

circles
//Enter
.enter().apend("circle").attr("r",5)
//Update
.merge(circles)
.attr("cx", function (d){ return scaleX; })
.attr("cy", function (d){ return scaleY; });

//Exit
circles.exit().remove();
};

    //Invoking the funktion with var xyr
render(xyr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `<script>` and `</script>` from the javascript part to insert your code as a code snipet. You can then use `https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js` to get rid of the next error. And finally fix the typo `apend` to `append` to have smthg displayed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First remove the `<script>` and `</script>` tags, those are throwing the errors. Second, you link v3 when your code is v4/5 (I used v4 in my snippet). Third you had some spelling mistakes that threw some errors. Lastly (and the biggest issue with d3 rendering), is with this:

```
.merge(circles)
.attr("cx", function (d){ return scaleX; })
.attr("cy", function (d){ return scaleY; });
```

which was missing the link to the data, which was updated to

```
.merge(circles)
.attr("cx", function (d){ return scaleX(d.x); })
.attr("cy", function (d){ return scaleY(d.y); });
```

```js
var xyr = [{
    x: 1,
    y: 1,
    r: 1
  },
  {
    x: 2,
    y: 2,
    r: 2
  },
  {
    x: 3,
    y: 3,
    r: 3
  }
];

var body = d3.select("body");
var svg = body.append("svg").attr("width", 250).attr("height", 250);

var scaleX = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 250]);
var scaleY = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 250]);

function render(data) {
  //Data Binding
  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);

  scaleX.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }));
  scaleY.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.y;
  }));

  //Debugging (working correct  --> 125)

  circles
    //Enter
    .enter().append("circle").attr("r", 5)
    //Update
    .merge(circles)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return scaleX(d.x);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return scaleY(d.y);
    });

  //Exit
  circles.exit().remove();
};

//Invoking the funktion with var xyr
render(xyr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I took this example frome this source: http://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToD3/examples/viewer/#/73  But obviously it works different when the data comes from a CSV-File

Comment: To whomever downvoted this, could I please know why so I can improve?